# Unable to import QtQuick 1.1 in Qt Creator 4.0.3

Tags: qt, qt-quick

I am using Qt Creator 4.0.3 and when looking at an older project using QtQuick 1.1  and trying to view in the designer, I get "Cannot open this QML document because of an error in QML file: Unsupported QtQuick version (0:0).

"Go to error" brings me to the line **import QtQuick 1.1** in my .qml file. I do not know if QtQuick 1.1 is loaded or available nor do I know how to find that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess the reason ist that QtQuick 1 was removed with Qt 5.6 (at least from the release packages).
[Qt_5.6 Removed_Modules](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.6#Removed_Modules)

Either Qt uses Qt 5.6/5.7 and/or was built with 5.6/5.7

You would need to build and use QtCreator with Qt 5.5 I guess.